# Error in JSON.parse() (when called from API Gateway)

Tags: arrays, json, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm working on AWS lambda + API Gateway, and I need to pass an array of numbers in the url (GET method) for a REST call. It seems a good way is to pass the numbers as string (comma separated) and then use JSON.parse for the conversion to an array of numbers.

Following is the AWS lambda code I'm using;

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var arr = JSON.parse('[' + event.numbers + ']');
    console.log("array: " + arr);

    // TODO implement
    callback(null, 'Hello from Lambda');
};
```

I'm testing this function in AWS Lambda using this Input test event;

```
{
  "numbers": "1,5"
}
```

And everything works as expected; no errors.

However, when I test it via API Gateway, and passing the numbers as string in the query, I get following error (observed via CloudWatch);

```
*19:19:02
START RequestId: eabab882-8cee-11e7-8e2f-79d3086e061f Version: $LATEST
19:19:02
2017-08-29T19:19:02.688Z    eabab882-8cee-11e7-8e2f-79d3086e061f    SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 1 at Object.parse (native) at exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:4:20)
19:19:02
END RequestId: eabab882-8cee-11e7-8e2f-79d3086e061f
19:19:02
REPORT RequestId: eabab882-8cee-11e7-8e2f-79d3086e061f  Duration: 215.25 ms Billed Duration: 300 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 18 MB
19:19:02
RequestId: eabab882-8cee-11e7-8e2f-79d3086e061f Process exited before completing request*
```

This is the request passed to lambda as shown in the log;

```
"body-json" : {},
"params" : {
"path" : {
    }
    ,"querystring" : {
        "numbers" : "1,6"
            }
    ,"header" : {
    }
    },
"stage-variables" : {
},
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, since I'm passing same string in both cases.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks
Gus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this input json informed, you need to get it like this:

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[' + event.params.querystring.numbers + ']');
```

rather than:

```
var arr = JSON.parse('[' + event.numbers + ']');
```

Or make a body mapping template to stay the way you want:

```
{ "number": "$input.params('number')" }
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html

I hope I have helped!